# adding more data to info window

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In my web app, the data comes from the `responseXML` property.  When I click a marker on a google map, it shows the address of the market in the information window. I also want to show the value of `openhours` in the info window. How would I do that?

Here is my code so far:

```
function display() {
    if ((xhr.readyState == 4) && (xhr.status == 200)) {
        var xmlDoc = xhr.responseXML;
        var market = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("market");
        for (var i = 0; i < market.length; i++) {
            var address = market[i].getElementsByTagName("address");
            address = address[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            var openhours = market[i].getElementsByTagName("openhours");
            openhours = openhours[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            geocoder.getLocations(address, addToMap);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its hard to understand what you need, where do the data come from? or what do you need exactly

Comment: Didn't you already ask this earlier?

Comment: @alex i have posted this again becoz i logged out and now unable to add any comment to my previous post

Comment: @lbu actually the data comes from responseXML property.when i am clicking marker on google map , it shows address of market in information window but i want to show the 'openhours' as well in the info window

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by changing this:

```
        map.openInfoWindowHtml(point, address);
```

To this:

```
        map.openInfoWindowHtml(point, address + '<br/>' + openhours);
```